# Ag-Grid wrong row orders in clipboard due to custom row node id

Tags: ag-grid

Ag-grid's default rowNodeId is an auto-increment number (0,1,2,3,4...)

For my application, I use a custom rowNodeId which is composed of values inside the grid, like: col_x_value + '#' + col_y_value + '#' + col_z_value:

```
this.gridOptions.getRowNodeId = (data) => {
    return myPkColumns
              .sort()
              .map(pk) => data[pk])
              .join('#')
```

Issue: When I copy rows to excel, the order in which the rows are pasted in Excel is not like the order I see on the grid.

The order does not seem to follow custom row node id neither..

One solution I have in mind is to use the default rowNodeId + a non-visible column to store the custom id. But this means I need to loop through the grid every time I need to find a specific row.

Any better solutions? Thanks

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "copy rows to excel" - are you selecting rows and copying them to the clipboard somehow, using the grid's "export to Excel" feature, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution I could think of is implementing callback `sendToClipboard(params)` so you can control the ordering before sending data to clipboard.

From the docs -

> If you want to do the copy to clipboard yourself (ie not use the grids
>   clipboard interaction) then implement the callback
>   sendToClipboard(params). Use this if you are in a non-standard web
>   container that has a bespoke API for interacting with the clipboard.
>   The callback gets the data to go into the clipboard, it's your job to
>   call the bespoke API.

Example [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-clipboard/#example-custom)